# How to get variable's value from URL and pass to all the links on the whole site? but ignore it if you just visit the home page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, variables

So I was trying to accomplish something like this

[how to get variable's value from URL and pass to all the links on the whole site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057943/how-to-get-variables-value-from-url-and-pass-to-all-the-links-on-the-whole-site)

But the problem I ran into is when you just visiting the home page or any page without the variable value it makes all links on the page to look like this:

http://www.website.com/page1/?http://www.website.com/

So it adds the whole url as a variable value, and what I need to accomplish is when you visit page

www.example.com/page1.php?var1=blabla

it keeps that variable value throughout the website, but if you just visit www.example.com/page1.php you won't see any variable value.

what do I need to change in this code to get rid of this problem

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1);
    var links = $('a');
    links.each(function(){
    var curLink=$(this);
    var href = curLink.attr('href');
    var newhref = href +'?'+ hashes; 
    curLink.attr('href',newhref);
    });
});
    </script>
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter ?

Comment: I've tried top 10 solutions from that page, and none of them passing the variable value to all links
so if I visit page like this www.example.com/page1.php?var1=blabla
links on that page doesn't contain ?var1=blabla

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1);
        if ( hashes != "" ) {
          var links = $('a');
          links.each(function(){
            var curLink=$(this);
            var href = curLink.attr('href');
            var newhref = href +'?'+ hashes; 
            curLink.attr('href',newhref);
          });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Still the same result, if I visit page without any variable I get links like this http://www.example.com/page1.php?http://www.example.com/page1.php

Comment: So If I visit page http://www.website.com/page1/ links on that page will look like http://www.website.com/page1/?http://www.website.com/page1/ and if I visit page http://www.website.com/page1/?var1=blabla every link would look like http://www.website.com/link2/?var1=blabla, and that's how I want it, I just don't want to use the whole url as a variable like in first example

Comment: All it should be doing is, if variable, add it to all links, if no variable, leave links untouched. Maybe you need to adjust the `if`-statement a little. What value does `hashes` have on a page whithout variables?

Comment: Not so sure the javascript is doing that, could be something in your permalinks, or .htaccess. Did you check the value of `hashes`? Or put an `alert('inside loop');` inside the `if`-loop to see if the actions are performed.

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question but how do I check the value of hashes? thank you for your time and help